# PostgresSQL - How to insert into main table and detail table in one stored procedure?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

so I'm working on a project which requires my query to insert into one main table and its detail table (which will be sent into the DB as a list) in one transaction so that it'll roll-back if one of the insert functions are failed.

Let's say I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE transaction(
  id             BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  user_id        BIGINT    FOREIGN KEY NOT NULL,
  total_item     INT                   NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  total_purchase BIGINT                NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
)

CREATE TABLE transaction_detail(
  id              BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  transaction_id  BIGINT    FOREIGN KEY NOT NULL,
  product_id      BIGINT    FOREIGN KEY NOT NULL,
  product_price   INT                   NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  purchase_amount INT                   NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
)
```

And I have this function:

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_transaction(order JSONB, product_list JSONB)`

Function Parameters:

- `order        : An object which will be inserted into the transaction table`
- `product_list : List of Product object which will be inserted into the transaction_detail table`

My current query looks something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_order(tx JSONB, product_list JSONB)
    RETURNS BIGINT
AS $$
WITH result AS (
    INSERT INTO transaction(
        user_id,
        total_item,
        total_purchase,
    ) VALUES (
        (tx ->> 'user_id') :: BIGINT,
        (tx ->> 'total_item') :: INT,
        (tx ->> 'total_purchase') :: INT,
    )
    RETURNING id AS transaction_id 
)
FOR row IN product_list LOOP
    INSERT INTO transaction_detail(
        transaction_id,
        product_id,
        product_price,
        purchase_amount,
    ) VALUES (
        transaction_id,
        (row ->> 'product_id') :: BIGINT,
        (row ->> 'product_price') :: INT,
        (row ->> 'purchase_amount') :: INT,
    )
END LOOP;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL SECURITY DEFINER;
```

JSON files:

- tx.json

`[
 "user_id" : "1",
 "total_item" : "2",
 "total_purchase" : "2000",
]`

- product_list.json

`[
  {
    "product_id" : "1",
    "product_price" : "500",
    "purchase_amount" : "2"
  },
  {
    "product_id" : "2",
    "product_price" : "1000",
    "purchase_amount" : "1"
  }
]`

I know something is wrong with my query although I can't put a finger on it.
Any pointer is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add some sample data on how your JSON values look like that you pass to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the data passed as `product_list`  is an array, you can do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_order(p_order JSONB, p_product_list JSONB)
    RETURNS BIGINT
AS $$
  WITH result AS (
      INSERT INTO "transaction"(
          user_id,
          total_item,
          total_purchase
      ) VALUES (
          (p_order ->> 'user_id') :: BIGINT,
          (p_order ->> 'total_item') :: INT,
          (p_order ->> 'total_purchase') :: INT
      )
      RETURNING id AS transaction_id 
  ), details as (
    INSERT INTO transaction_detail(
        transaction_id,
        product_id,
        product_price,
        purchase_amount
    ) 
    select r.transaction_id, 
           (pl.data ->> 'product_id')::bigint,
           (pl.data ->> 'product_price')::int,
           (pl.data ->> 'purchase_amount')::int
    from result r,
      jsonb_array_elements(p_product_list) as pl(data)
  )
  select transaction_id 
  from result;
$$ 
LANGUAGE SQL SECURITY DEFINER;
```

I renamed the parameters to avoid name clashes with reserved keywords. By prefixing the parameter names you also avoid name clashes with column or table names. `order` is a reserved keyword and can only be used when quoted, e.g. `"order"`. `transaction` is a keyword however it's not reserved, but it's better to quote it nonetheless.

The insert into the transaction details needs to be an `INSERT...SELECT` selecting from the `result` to get the generated transaction id and by unnesting the array elements in the product list JSON value.

The final select of the CTE then returns the generated transaction id.

You can call the function like this:

```
select insert_order('{"user_id": 42, "total_item": 1, "total_purchase": 100}'::jsonb, 
                    '[ {"product_id": 1, "product_price": 10, "purchase_amount": 1}, 
                       {"product_id": 2, "product_price": 20, "purchase_amount": 2}, 
                       {"product_id": 3, "product_price": 30, "purchase_amount": 3} ]'::jsonb);
```